# Unable to install app on Xcode 15 - Failed to verify code signature

Tags: xcode, installation, xcode15

The installation of my app was working fine before, and literally nothing changed when I tried to run it on my device, but I'm getting the following error when trying to install (iOS 17.1.1, Xcode 15.0.1):

> "Unable to install {app name}"
>
> Failed to verify code signature of {path name} (a valid provisioning
> profile for this executable was not found).
>
> Verify that the Developer App certificate for your account is trusted on your device. Open
> Settings on the device and navigate to General -> VPN & Device
> Management, then select your Developer App certificate to trust it.

Problem is, I can't grant that permission under General -> VPN & Device Management, nothing of the sorts shows up there.

I was searching for 30 minutes before finding a solution, so posting here in case it is useful to some folks!

Comment: Have you checked that the correct provisioning profile is set in Xcode for the target you built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Apple forum post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737156) covers the same issue. Some quotes:

> Not quite show how I fixed it. But by some combination of deleting derived data, restarting my phone, and reinstalling Xcode 15 release candidate it now work.

> Had to remove the app completly from the device -> "Touch and hold the app icon on the Home Screen, ... tap Delete App".

Clean install worked for me.